# Removing duplicate lines from a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, loops, dictionary

I may be going in to wrong direction here so looking for some assistance.

Basically just now, I have a script that opens up a log file and picks out any lines that match a value. With these lines, I then check to see if a key in a dictionary is found and then prints the line. 
I'm not wanting it to print every line, just if it matches once.

So far I have this but can't seem to `break` in order to only show one match

For this example, my `syslog` file is:

```
PHASE 1
PHASE 2
PHASE 2
```

Code:

```
phase_dict = {
"PHASE 1": "Phase 1 completed successfully: ",
"PHASE 2": "Phase 2 completed successfully: ",
}

with FileReadBackwards('syslog', encoding="utf-8") as frb:
    for line in frb:
        if re.findall('first_match', line):
            for key,value in phase_dict.iteritems():
                if re.search(key, line):
                    print value + line.rstrip()
```

My output shows:

```
Phase 2 completed successfully: PHASE 2
Phase 2 completed successfully: PHASE 2
Phase 1 completed successfully: PHASE 1
```

I'm trying to get it to only show one match for each.

Expected output:

```
Phase 2 completed successfully: PHASE 2
Phase 1 completed successfully: PHASE 1
```

I'm not sure if I'm going down the best route in going through the dictionary and using the `for` loops

Any help would be appreciated

Cheers!

Comment: What in the world is `FileReadBackwards`?

Comment: I was using [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/file-read-backwards)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no knowledge of what `FileReadBackwards` is...

1. You can just keep a `set` of seen phases.
2. `dict` supports random access, so there's no need to iterate over them, much less use regex on them.

```
from __future__ import print_function

seen = set()
with FileReadBackwards('syslog', encoding="utf-8") as frb:
    for line in frb:
        line = line.strip()
        if line not in seen and line in phase_dict:
            seen.add(line)
            print(phase_dict[line] + line)
```